# Detect missing 'commitAnimations'

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation

Something weird is happening to my views all of a sudden (resizing a UITableView results in strange flying header sections) and I have a feeling I'm missing a '[UIVIew commitAnimations]' somewhere in code. When I add this line into 'viewForHeaderInSection', the weird behavior stops.

Question is, how can I find animation blocks with missing 'commitAnimations' statements? I've given the code a manual look and couldn't find anything. It's also a huge project and I can't see where something might have gone wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command+Shift+F ("Find in Project") and type "[UIView beginAnimations" with the "contains" option and you should be able to find all of the instances in your project where the `[UIView commitAnimations]` should be.